# Are these functions call equivalent?

Tags: javascript

Recently I have seen these functions in tutorials. Are they equivalent?

```
(_ => console.log(1))();

(() => console.log(1))();
```

Comment: They are equivalent. Both print "1" to the console.

Comment: But why the use of _ and () as anonymous functions, are the same? Why use _?

Comment: It is sometimes written that way for brevity. It usually means "ignored".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions do exactly the same thing. The only difference is that the top function takes one parameter, `_`, while the other takes zero. This doesn't matter in this example, since you don't use the `_` variable.

If however, you are using `_` as a variable name, and you use it in the function, you will run into problems. Example:

```
(_ => console.log(_))();
```

is not the same thing as

```
(() => console.log(_))();
```

In the first line, the function prints the value of the parameter `_`, which, in this case is `undefined`, since no value is passed to it. In the second line, the function prints the value of the global variable `_`. This can become a problem if you use a library like underscore.js, where the variable `_` is used.

Comment: While both produce the same output internally they are different, correct?

Answer (score 1):

A "fat arrow" (`=>`) function can be declared with a single identifier parameter name, or with a parenthesized lists of zero or more parameters. Your first example

```
(_ => console.log(1))();
```

is the first case, with the parameter name being "_". The second example is a parameter list with no parameters:

```
(() => console.log(1))();
```

Neither function makes use of its parameters, and both invocations pass no parameters. That is, both function calls have no actual arguments; the statements both end with `()`. Whether the two are "equivalent" or not depends on your definition of "equivalent". In both cases, exactly the same thing will happen. However, the anonymous fat-arrow functions are not exactly the same.

Comment: In the Erlang programming language, parameters that are explicitly to be considered as "ignored" start with an underscore. Fun fact.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. The first is an anonymous fat arrow function with 1 parameter, the second is an anonymous fat arrow function with 0 parameters. The first, thus, relies on the fact that passing too few arguments to a function is not an error in ECMAScript.

The underscore `_` is sometimes used to indicate a parameter that is required to fulfill a certain contract but is actually ignored. However, in this case, that is a misuse of this convention since the parameter *isn't* required: the function is called without arguments, so there is no need to declare a parameter.